# compare 2 spark RDD to make sure that value from first is in the range of the second RDD

Tags: apache-spark

there are 2  very large RDD(each has more than milion records), the first is :

```
rdd1.txt(name,value):    
chr1    10016 
chr1    10017 
chr1    10018 
chr1    20026 
chr1    20036 
chr1    25016 
chr1    26026
chr2    40016 
chr2    40116 
chr2    50016 
chr3    70016 

rdd2.txt(name,min,max):
chr1     10000  20000
chr1     20000  30000
chr2     40000  50000
chr2     50000  60000
chr3     70000  80000
chr3    810001  910000
chr3    860001  960000
chr3    910001  1010000
```

the value is valid only when it's in the range  between the Min and Max of the second RDD , the count of  the name's occurs will plus 1 if its valid

Take the above as an example,   the chr1's  occurs 7.

how can i get the result in scala with spark?

many thanks

Comment: Why is the column in the second rdd not unique? Does that mean that we can just if the value in the first rdd fits in any of the second?

Comment: the second RDD defines a range for  the value in RDD1

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
val rdd1 = sc.parallelize(Seq(
  ("chr1", 10016 ), ("chr1", 10017), ("chr1", 10018)))
val rdd2 = sc.parallelize(Seq(
   ("chr1", 10000, 20000), ("chr1",20000, 30000)))

rdd1.toDF("name", "value").join(rdd2.toDF("name", "min", "max"), Seq("name"))
 .where($"value".between($"min", $"max"))
```

Comment: scala> r1.toDF("name", "value").join(r2.toDF("name", "min", "max"),              Seq("name")).where($"value".between($"min", $"max"))
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: The number of  columns doesn't match.
    Old column names (1): _1
    New column names (2): name, value

Comment: If I understand correctly, you could also `rdd1.toDF("name","min","max").groupBy('name).agg(min('min).as("min"),max('max).as("max"))` before joining for making it more efficient (I'm pretty sure it's an optimization....)

Comment: i'll try it and check if it's more efficient after i have a complete answer for my question

Answer (score 0):

As I understand , you want values from rdd1 that fall between min and max in rdd2. Please see if the below works

```
val rdd1 = sc.parallelize(Seq(("chr1", 10016 ), ("chr1", 10017), ("chr1", 10018)))
val rdd2 = sc.parallelize(Seq(("chr1", 10000, 20000), ("chr1",20000, 30000)))
rdd1.toDF("name", "value").join(rdd2.toDF("name", "min", "max"), Seq("name")).where($"value".between($"min", $"max")).groupBy($"name").count().show()


scala> val rdd1=sc.parallelize(Seq(("chr1",    10016 ),("chr1",    10017 ),("chr1",    10018 ),("chr1",    20026 ),("chr1",    20036 ),("chr1",    25016 ),("chr1",    26026),("chr2",    40016 ),("chr2",    40116 ),("chr2",    50016 ),("chr3",    70016 )))
rdd1: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(String, Int)] = ParallelCollectionRDD[33] at parallelize at <console>:24

scala> val rdd2=sc.parallelize(Seq(("chr1",     10000,  20000),("chr1",     20000 , 30000),("chr2",     40000  ,50000),("chr2",     50000  ,60000),("chr3",     70000  ,80000),("chr3",    810001  ,910000),("chr3",    860001  ,960000),("chr3",    910001  ,1010000)))
rdd2: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(String, Int, Int)] = ParallelCollectionRDD[34] at parallelize at <console>:24


scala> rdd1.toDF("name", "value").join(rdd2.toDF("name", "min", "max"), Seq("name")).where($"value".between($"min", $"max")).groupBy($"name").count().show()
+----+-----+
|name|count|
+----+-----+
|chr3|    1|
|chr1|    7|
|chr2|    3|
+----+-----+
```

**Edits**
If you are reading from a file , i would use the following

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.{StructType, StructField, StringType, IntegerType};

val sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc)
val nameValueSchema = StructType(Array(StructField("name", StringType, true),StructField("value", IntegerType, true)))
val nameMinMaxSchema = StructType(Array(StructField("name", StringType, true),StructField("min", IntegerType, true),StructField("max", IntegerType, true)))
val rdd1 = sqlContext.read.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").option("header", "false").schema(nameValueSchema).load("rdd1.csv")
val rdd2 = sqlContext.read.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").option("header", "false").schema(nameMinMaxSchema).load("rdd2.csv")
rdd1.toDF("name", "value").join(rdd2.toDF("name", "min", "max"), Seq("name")).where($"value".between($"min", $"max")).groupBy($"name").count().show()
```

This will run on all nodes and there is no need of parallelize call. Quoting the [documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.SparkContext) here

> def parallelize[T](seq: Seq[T], numSlices: Int =
>   defaultParallelism)(implicit arg0: ClassTag[T]): RDD[T]  Permalink
>   Distribute a local Scala collection to form an RDD.

Comment: many thanks for the complete instruction and the result is expected, but the  rdd1.txt and rdd2.txt is very very large , how to get it parallelized without the hardcoding?

Comment: Not sure i understand  parallelizing without hardcoding , can you elaborate ?

Comment: What do you mean by hard coding @WuFei ?

Comment: hello, i only know that parallelize() work on a list , but how to parallelize on  a large txt file? like    parallelize(("file:///data/rdd2.txt")? many thanks for the help

Comment: @RamachandranGA how is your answer different than the first answer provided by @LostInOverflow?

Comment: @Wilmerton , thanks for pointing out. I did not check honestly , i was trying it out to see what was the error and posted both the earlier posters answer as well as the one that worked for me. As for the edits , i just added read from a csv.I will remove my first answer if that is a violation. Apologies , plagiarism was not intended

Comment: @RamachandranGA, 2 more questions:  1: how about a file of Spaces Separated Values instead of cvs format?   2:  does this api support variable length columns(the columns of every row is not all equal in RDD2.TXT)?